# Use Oracle trigger to populate a table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I am trying to track a failed user login into an Oracle database for monitoring purposes. The plan is to use a trigger on database logon. The table is created and the trigger is associated with the table successfully. The table CREATE statement and the TRIGGER are  successful. When checking the table values oracle returns no records.  How can I accomplish this?

```
--create table

CREATE TABLE myschema.errors(
    user_name VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL ENABLE,
        error_code VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL ENABLE,
            error_message VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL ENABLE,
               error_time timestamp)
                 TABLESPACE "USERS";

--create application context
CREATE CONTEXT myschema6_ctx USING myschema.myschema6_pkg; 

--create package body
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY myschema.myschema6_pkg 
    IS 
        c_context CONSTANT VARCHAR2(30) := 'myschema6_ctx';
    username  VARCHAR2(30);
    My_USER  VARCHAR2(30);
 
            PROCEDURE set_contexts IS 
            BEGIN 
            SELECT SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER') into username FROM DUAL;
            SELECT SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'OS_USER') into My_USER FROM DUAL;
            DBMS_SESSION.SET_CONTEXT ( c_context, username, My_USER); 
    END; 
            END myschema6_pkg; 
                / 

--create trigger
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER myschema6_ctx_trig AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE
    DECLARE 
    My_USER VARCHAR2(30);
        v_code VARCHAR2(30);
        v_errm VARCHAR2(30);
    BEGIN
        myschema.myschema6_pkg.set_contexts;
        SELECT SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'OS_USER') into My_USER FROM DUAL;
            EXCEPTION
                WHEN OTHERS THEN
                   v_code := SQLCODE;
                   v_errm := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1 , 64);

                   -- to insert information about errors.
                INSERT INTO myschema.errors(user_name,error_code,error_message,error_time)
                VALUES(My_USER,v_code,v_errm, SYSTIMESTAMP);
    END;
/
```

Comment: I don't follow the plan.  A logon trigger will fire after a user successfully logs in to the database (at least passing the basic authentication).  Your login trigger appears to write a row every time someone logs in successfully and does nothing if a user fails to log in.  The package and context also appear to be unnecessary.  Is there a reason that you're not auditing failed logins instead (which is the default in any recent Oracle version)?

Comment: Hi Justin. Thank you for your clarification question. I agree with Paul and you on AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE triggers. These triggers will not capture failed logins. I still need to use application context for logged in users. I would use AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE for successful logged in users. However I will use unified_audit_trails for auditing purpose.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use "`AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE`" triggers to capture logon failures. A logon failure never successfully logs on, so such a trigger will never be executed.

You can, however, capture a logon failure with an "`AFTER SERVERERROR ON DATABASE`" trigger, which fires whenever an ORA- exception is raised to the calling client, and that would include any error message at logon (invalid password, account locked, etc..). Within the trigger, look at `server_error(1)` and look for values of mainly `28000`, `1017` and `1005` (they are positive, not negative). Just be aware that for logon failures, the `USERNAME` in `v$session` will be `NULL`. You have to get the intended username by looking at `SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','AUTHENTICATED_IDENTITY')`.

Also, there is no need to use packages or set contexts. You can access everything you need in the trigger either with the standard `SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV',...)` calls or by hitting V$ views like `v$session` with your SID. Lastly, in any trigger being used to write to a log, you will want to make it an autonomous transaction and include a COMMIT:

```
DECLARE
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
  INSERT ...

  COMMIT;
END;
```

However, for simplicity I recommend that you first try Oracle's standard logon auditing. If it's enabled, simply query `DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL` for logon failures:

```
SELECT *
  FROM dba_audit_trail
 WHERE action_name = 'LOGON'
   AND returncode <> 0
```

Or if using Unified auditing:

```
SELECT *
  FROM unified_audit_trail
 WHERE action_name = 'LOGON'
   AND return_code <> 0
```

Only go with the system error trigger if you really need enriched information about the client that auditing doesn't provide.

Comment: Hi Paul. Thank you for your explanation on using "AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE" vs "AFTER SERVERERROR ON DATABASE". I agree with your answer and will simply use the unified_audit_trail to accomplish the auditing.